# Exporting large character vector as CSV-file in R

Tags: r, memory, vector, export, export-to-csv

I've been searching to find a suitable answer for my problem, but haven't found the exact or suitable answer.

I have a large character vector (about 4 million elements, well over 3GB in size). I want to output/export this large character vector as a CSV file in which each element represents a row.

Exporting this file with a `write.table`, `write.csv` or `write.csv2` results in memory allocation issues.

For now, I have tried the `RSQLite` package and the `fwrite` function from the `data.table` package. Both don't seem to work for different reasons.

- The `RQSLite` approach took +4 hours to process and I eventually had to kill it.
- The `fwrite()` function asks for a `data.frame` as input. Trying to coerce the large character vector into a data.frame, I ran into memory issues again.

Does anyone know a good approach to this problem?

(I am on a Windows 64bit machine, 16GB RAM, 500GB SSD and run R version 3.2.5)

Comment: If you are on Windows, look at `memory.size()`

Comment: What if you do `x <- list(x); setDT(x)` and then use `fwrite`? Also memory problems?

Comment: I would give @docendodiscimus 's solution a try first, and if that still has trouble, you can always break it into smaller pieces where you only do 100,000 elements at a time within a `for` loop.

Comment: @docendodiscimus: Works prefect! Thanks. Why don't you write it as an answer so I can flag it as the correct answer.

Comment: @wake_wake, great, I'll write up a short answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you might be able to convert your character vector `x` into a `list` and then use `data.table::setDT` to convert it to a `data.table` *by reference*, i.e. without copy. So it would be:

```
x <- list(x)
library(data.table)
setDT(x)
```

Now you can use for example `data.table`'s new `fwrite` function to create the csv-file.